# Type T does not satisfy the constraint DialogData - Angular 16.2.12 - TinyMCE 5.10.9

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-5, angular16

After upgrading to Angular 16 from versions 14 and 15, I encountered an error when launching my app:

```
Error: node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts:864:42 - error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'DialogData'.

864     onTabChange?: DialogTabChangeHandler<T>;
                                             ~

  node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts:853:22
    853 interface DialogSpec<T> {
                             ~
    This type parameter might need an `extends DialogData` constraint.
```

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.11
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.2.11
@angular/cli                    16.2.11
@schematics/angular             16.2.11
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.9.3
tinymce                         5.10.9
tslib                           2.6.2
zone.js                         0.13.3

Angular CLI: 16.2.11
Node: 18.16.1
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
```

I've tried fixing it by modifying the file `tinymce.d.ts` at line 853 to: `interface DialogSpec<T extends DialogData>`, and it resolves the issue. However, after each `npm install`, the file gets restored, and my fix is lost. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any relevant documentation on this issue. Any help on a more permanent solution would be greatly appreciated.

By activating `skipLibCheck` in `tsconfig.json` it work, but not sure hiding these errors is the best idea.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    ...
}
```